# Sybase AnyWhere DB not releasing disk space

Tags: sql, sybase, diskspace, sqlanywhere, defragmentation

I have a Sybase Anywhere DB which is like almost worth 10 GBs. I know there are 2 tables which are really huge in this DB, so i truncated these 2 tables but the size of the DB still does not go down but keeps in increasing. Is there any other way than Recreating the DB which would release the disk space from this database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SQL Anywhere will not release space as data is removed from the database. It will keep the space as free pages for later use. To reclaim the space, you'll need to rebuild the database.